# How to fix the SELECT that use a virtual Table using Group by

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to get the count of EventType by month.

I've trying the next 2 possibility:
First possibility

```
DECLARE @StartDate date

    SET @StartDate = GETDATE() - 365;

    WITH theDates AS
     (SELECT @StartDate as theDate
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, theDate)
        FROM theDates
       WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, 1, theDate) <= GETDATE()
     )

    SELECT 'Diagnosis' as EventType,
            MONTH(theDate), 
            YEAR(theDate),
            concat(MONTH(theDate),'/', YEAR(theDate)),
            Count(fpd.DateOfServiceID) as Eventcount
    FROM theDates dd
    LEFT JOIN fact.FactPatientDiagnosis fpd ON fpd.DateOfServiceID = concat(YEAR(theDate), MONTH(theDate), DAY(theDate))
    GROUP BY  YEAR(dd.theDate), MONTH(dd.theDate)
```

I've getting the value 0 for the EventCount Column 
But i know that are in the table more than 500 Diagnosis

Second Possibility

```
DECLARE @StartDate date

    SET @StartDate = GETDATE() - 365;


    WITH theDates AS
     (SELECT @StartDate as theDate
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, theDate)
        FROM theDates
       WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, 1, theDate) <= GETDATE()
     )

    SELECT 'Diagnosis' as EventType,
            MONTH(theDate), 
            YEAR(theDate),
            concat(MONTH(theDate),'/', YEAR(theDate)),
            Count(fpd.DateOfServiceID) as Eventcount
    FROM theDates dd
    LEFT JOIN fact.FactPatientDiagnosis fpd ON fpd.DateOfServiceID is not NULL
    GROUP BY  YEAR(dd.theDate), MONTH(dd.theDate)
```

In this Select, I've getting the value 503 for the EventCount column

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a database tag would help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want:

```
SET @StartDate = GETDATE() - 365;

WITH theDates AS (
      SELECT @StartDate as theDate
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, theDate)
      FROM theDates
      WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, 1, theDate) <= GETDATE()
     )
SELECT 'Diagnosis' as EventType,
       YEAR(theDate), MONTH(theDate), 
       concat(MONTH(theDate), '/', YEAR(theDate)),
       Count(fpd.DateOfServiceID) as Eventcount
FROM theDates dd LEFT JOIN
     fact.FactPatientDiagnosis fpd
     ON fpd.DateOfServiceID >= dd.theDate AND
        fpd.DateOfServiceID < DATEADD(month, 1, dd.theDate) 
GROUP BY YEAR(dd.theDate), MONTH(dd.theDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(dd.theDate), MONTH(dd.theDate);
```

Comment: When i executed this request, i've getting the next error: Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Comment: theDate column is of type Date but the DateOfServiceID column is of type int

Comment: For the first answer i've getting the next error: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime. and for the second answer i've getting the next error: Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int . Could you help me to resolve this error, thanks?

Comment: @user2422556 . . . Fix your data model.  That has nothing to do with the question that you asked.  You should be storing date/times using the appropriate type.  This is *especially* true in a column called `date`.

Comment: we receive date data as int from files and the were some reasons to stay with this type.

Answer (score 0):

You are generating 1 date for each month in CTE (picking current DAY), and comparing it with `dateofserviceid`, even some date matches, every day you will get different output.

Ideally you should be comparing only `YEAR` and `MONTH` part for the `JOIN`.

```
LEFT JOIN fact.factpatientdiagnosis fpd ON 
      month(fpd.dateofserviceid) = month(thedate) 
      AND 
      year(fpd.dateofserviceid) = year(thedate)
```

Your overall query should look like following now.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE 

SET @StartDate = Getdate() - 365; 

WITH thedates 
     AS (SELECT @StartDate AS theDate 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT Dateadd(month, 1, thedate) 
         FROM   thedates 
         WHERE  Dateadd(month, 1, thedate) <= Getdate()) 
SELECT 'Diagnosis'                AS EventType, 
       Month(thedate), 
       Year(thedate), 
       Concat(Month(thedate), '/', Year(thedate)), 
       Count(fpd.dateofserviceid) AS Eventcount 
FROM   thedates dd 
       LEFT JOIN fact.factpatientdiagnosis fpd 
              ON Month(fpd.dateofserviceid) = Month(thedate) 
                 AND Year(fpd.dateofserviceid) = Year(thedate) 
GROUP  BY Year(dd.thedate), 
          Month(dd.thedate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you ever want to use Int for a date IDK. I assume your DateOfServiceID is a date representation in int format like 20180102 (yyyyMMdd). If so:

```
WITH myData (theDate)
AS (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, CAST(DateOfServiceId AS VARCHAR(8)), 112)
    FROM fact.FactPatientDiagnosis
    WHERE DateOfServiceId >= CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, -365, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)), 112) AS INT))
SELECT 'Diagnosis' AS EventType,
       MONTH(theDate) AS mn,
       YEAR(theDate) AS yr,
       SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), theDate, 103), 4, 7) AS MonthYear,
       COUNT(theDate) AS Eventcount
FROM myData
GROUP BY MONTH(theDate),
         YEAR(theDate),
         SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), theDate, 103), 4, 7)
ORDER BY YEAR(theDate),
         MONTH(theDate);
```

Comment: Your answer give the same not right result as the previous answers

Comment: @user2422556, what do you mean by "not right result"? What is the right result for you? Where is your sample data and expected output?